# Get the range (or values) of a table column Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the cell range of the second column of a table in Excel using VBA code, and to automatically update this range if there are new entries in the table every time a userform initializes. At first I thought this would be easy, but right now I'm completely lost and can't figure out how to make my code work. There might be something I'm missing.

I searched on this forum and found two possible solutions, the first one is:

```
Sub test()
    Dim table As ListObject
    Set table = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    Debug.Print table.ListColumns(2).Range.Rows.Count
End Sub
```

This code kinda works. It successfully recognizes the `Table1` with all new rows every time I run it. The issue is that it identifies the entire table, I just want to the get the range of a single column. No matter what I do, the variable `table` always gets the range of the whole table.

I found a second approach as follows:

```
Sub test()
    Dim tbl as ListObject
    Dim rng as Range
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    Set rng = tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
End Sub
```

This code also kinda works, but only if the table has a single row of data. If my table only has a single row of data the variable `rng` identifies the table and row without issues. However, the value of the variable is the value of the cell, like "Sample Text", and not the cell range. And if I try to add any more rows the variable `rng` remains empty.

I would really appreciate any guidance with this. I should also mention that I want to get the range of a column that belongs to said table even when actively using a different worksheet, like `C3:C5`. And when more data is entered to get an updated range like `C3:C80`. I don't want to select the range neither, just get that information and use it for other purposes.

Comment: Your second example works just fine for me in capturing an entire column of data in a table, excluding the header. It works for tables with many rows. If your table has, for example, three columns named Red, Green, and Blue, an alternative approach could also be `Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("Table1[Green]")`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. It's just brilliant. You just helped me simplify my code a lot. Have a good day Sir!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code already returns all of the Data for the specified column.  You can see this by adding to your Sub (after `Set rng = ...`), and look at the output in the Immediate Window

```
Sub test()
    Dim tbl as ListObject
    Dim rng as Range
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    Set rng = tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange

    Debug.Print rng.Address
    Dim cl As Range
    For Each cl In rng
        Debug.Print cl.Address, cl.Value
    Next
End Sub
```

As to your 2nd question, change

```
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
```

to

```
Set tbl = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NameOfTableSheet").ListObjects("Table1")
```

You may want to specify the specific Workbook too.

```
Set tbl = Workbooks("NameOfWorkbook").Worksheets("NameOfTableSheet").ListObjects("Table1")
```

Comment: That’s what I was missing. I didn’t know you could do something like ‘rng.Address’ to get the actual range. Thank you for your help!